# Wordpress get the category fields even if there is no post

Tags: wordpress

I have one small problem, i am showing the custom fields of category on category page. its showing fine. but its not showing if there is no post in that category.

i don't know where to use the 'hide_empty' => 0 in my code.

here is the code which i used to show the fields of category.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category');

if( !empty($terms) ) {

$term = array_pop($terms);
$expert_photo = get_field('expert_photo',$term);
$expert_name = get_field('expert_name',$term);
$expert_title = get_field('expert_title',$term);
$expert_description = get_field('expert_description',$term);
$expert_introduction = get_field('expert_introduction',$term);
```

Answer (score 0):

get_the_terms function is retrieve the terms of the taxonomy that are attached to the post.

If you want to get all category, you can use this code

```
$categories =  get_categories(array('orderby'=>'name','hide_empty'=>false));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($categories);
```